# Can I replace a quad breaker with a tandem breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

My panel has a 15-amp breaker for two-bathroom outlets and two outdoor outlets. Is that normal? I would like to replace that with a 20 amp breaker. Also, I want to replace my water boiler with the "Ecosmart ECO 36 - 36kw 240V 150A Electric Tankless Water Heater" but that requires 4 x 40 amp breakers (my electrical panel is 200 amps).

So I'm trying to make room for it on my electrical panel by replacing the quad breaker with a single-pole tandem 20 amp breaker since the water boiler won't need the quad breaker anymore. Is all of that possible and correct to do?

In the future, I will remove the furnace and replace it with an all-in-one heat pump, perhaps some of the furnace breaker slots will be freed up.

Another thing to note is that my refrigerator and microwave are on the same line and when the toaster and microwave get used the microwave power dims a bit. My microwave keeps dying every few years. Perhaps the fridge and microwave should be on their own breaker, right now it feels like too many things are competing for power on that line/breaker. My electrical panel is exactly the way the electrician left it when the home was made in 2006, except for the labels.

[image: My Electrical Panel - Replace Breakers.]

[image: Eaton Cutler-Hammer Single-Pole BR Type Circuit Breaker, 20-Amp, 120-240-Volt.]

[image: Cutler-Hammer BD2020 Type BD Circuit Breaker, 120 VAC, 20 A, 10 kA, 1 Pole, Thermal Magnetic Trip.]

[image: My Electrical Panel.]

[image: My Electrical Panel - 200 Amps.]

Comment: You can't change the bathroom breaker to a 20 Amp unless you verify that the wire connected to that breaker is #12 AWG CU or #10 AWG AL.

Comment: The single 15A breaker feeding outlets in even one bathroom is substandard by current code, which requires a 20A breaker for that purpose. I think it can be shared across bathrooms, though that's not a great idea depending on loads (hairdryers, etc.) Normal for the time, perhaps, since it seems to be "lumping all the GFCI loads on one breaker" for an era before the loads for bathrooms were increased and the places GFCIs were needed were increased.

Comment: @ecnerwal is correct 20 amp is the standard today and can feee 2 bathrooms.

Comment: This is way too many questions in one Q.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by replacing your existing water heater with a tankless unit?

Comment: "The single 15A breaker feeding outlets in even one bathroom is substandard by current code." Even as a non-expert I kept wondering why the supposed expert electrician would wire this house like that. That 15A GFCI line goes to two bathrooms outlets and one outside outlet. I really hate how this house was wired and my kitchen can barely handle running a microwave and a toaster at the same even if by accident. Microwaves don't survive more than a few years in this house while trying to compete with all the other appliances on the same line/breaker.

Comment: I was really hoping that it was a more simple fix of splitting the lines and giving certain appliances their own dedicated breaker. Access to the wall/floor is so easy in this house for running new wire, I can do that myself. But no I'll probably need to reinstall everything and upgrade the panel and electrical service to 400A for near $10,000. That would be a nightmarish cost, I don't know what the cost would be and I'm trying not to think about that right this moment.

Comment: @j... you have not installed many electric on demand water heaters, in my answer I provided an example of a residence that the owner wanted to go to on demand electric , an all electric home this usually requires a 320a continuous panel or a 30/40,  150 for the wh and 120 for the furnace and you are at 170 amps turn the oven on and 1 surface element and with normal lighting we are over 300a I have installed a few of these and some smaller ones in the 90 amp range the smaller required point of use in the bathrooms 30 amps each for those because pressure fluctuations affect tankless temps.

Comment: @AngelD213 -- it'd probably help if you split your questions about reworking the rest of the wiring out from this into a separate question.  Anyway, to get back to the major issue here: what specific *problem* are you trying to solve by replacing your existing water heater with an electric tankless heater?

Answer (score 8):

I would SERIOUSLY reconsider an on demand, tankless electric water heater.   All the hype about the tankless: IE: Why keep 50+ gallons of water hot all the time when you don't use it?   Well, once the water is heated it pretty much stays heated given the quality of the insulation on electric water heaters these days. While tankless gas WH might make some sense (I still don't like them), a tankless electric WH is a MAJOR POWER DRAW and more complicated than a tank type.

I don't think you'll ever get cost recovery on the small energy savings you might get from a tankless.   Have you considered a HP water heater?  I don't know a lot about them, but they operate on a heat pump principle.  I hear their recover time is very slow, but there are real energy savings there.

Comment: Heat pumps are mandated for electric in my county but the utility had a rebate that paid all but a few bucks, the only problem I see if they are inside the home the cold air is discharged in the “closet” requiring that space to be heated, it would be nice if they vented to the outside. I have had tankless gas and additional point of use electric and thought that was the best combination and it worked well with a 3 bathroom home.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes. They are great in southern climes if installed in a hot garage.  But I see little benefit in re-heating the cold air discharged from a HP WH when installed in conditioned living space.   I have an indirect WH powered by propane fired boilers (mostly for hydronic heating)...just doing my part to contribute to global warming.

Comment: @george if you fail to heat the room with the heat pump WH, it will simply become very inefficient, then stop working altogether.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Agreed: It's like trading one problem for another.

Comment: I know this is a US context but in the U.K., tankless boilers (known as combi boilers) are generally considered to be the better option. One of the main benefits is you never run out of hot water.

Comment: It's not a saving issued but more of a space issue. The tankless can be put on the wall and it's 17 by 19 and under 5" thick. We have a very small utility room and would like that space for something like a linen closet. We're currently making home improvements and upgrades. I guess my current electrical panel should be dumped and replaced by a newer one that is more properly wired, I just hope it doesn't cost me more than $2,500 or go way over budget.

Comment: *savings issue [sorry about the misspellings].

Comment: @AngelD213, do you have natural gas available on the property?  A gas tankless may get you the space savings without necessitating a costly electrical service upgrade.

Comment: Who heats up domestic HW to 80C?  That's dangerously hot for DHW.  Here in the US a typical setting is  closer to 50C.   Yeah, somebody is probably going to pop off about legionnaires disease, but fact is about 50C is a common setting.

Comment: Did I read your panel right?  It looks like you are supplying your existing WH with a 20 amp circuit?  30 is more typical. Is your existing WH providing enough hot water?   It seems like a huge leap to go from a 20 amp circuit to a 150 amp circuit.

Comment: @J...I respect your comments, but this is getting opinion based and chatty, something we shouldn't be doing here.   Maybe Legionella is more common elsewhere, but everything I've seen on water heaters here in the US recommends 120-130 F. In keeping with SE guidelines, I won't comment on this anymore.  Maybe we just need to agree to disagree! Take care. EDIT:  Oops. Just reread your comment (last part) and agree completely about being able to have a store of hot water ready to go that was heated with only 4.5KW vs "10 times that amount".   I'm not at all a fan of electric tankless WHs.

Comment: @j... tankless water heaters do not store the water so high temp is not needed to kill legionaries, a pressure tank is not heated the water goes straight to the tap just as a tankless I agree with George you don’t have to heat the water you don’t on the cold tap.+ but I am also not a fan of electric tankless.

Answer (score 7):

First NO you cannot just change breaker sizes.

Second is your panel even rated for tandem or double stuff breakers?

And last ARE YOU KIDDING?
You want to put a 150 amp water heater on a 200 amp service, do you plan on turning all the lights off unplugging the refrigerator and freezer so you can cook dinner on the range? Also make sure the dryer and furnace is off.

No your service is not even close to large enough to put that water heater in.

You will need a 30/40 panel at least some call a 320/400 panel.

From experience you should first find someone with a similar model.
I have upgraded a customers service installed a similar sized unit, then added point of use kitchen and bath and the home owner was not happy / upset and had me return the system to a tanked system after almost 20k spent.

You would not be able to get a permit with the existing service panel.

Comment: Approaching the Green Acres electrical system!  LOL

Comment: That panel looks acceptable as is for current loads, Ed Beal:  Would it be possible (IE code legal) for the OP to simply add a 2nd 200 amp panel and upgrade the meter base to a class 320 service?   Or would he get tied up with a lot of other upgrades (AFCI, GFCI, etc.) EDIT:  POCO would have to verify feed wires could support class 320, I would bet.

Comment: That would be 2 service panels it can not be done without having a disconnect at the meter, but that is code once the 2020 code is accepted by the jurisdiction.  The existing panel probably has mixed grounds& neutrals and this would have to be changed so it could be done but with all the required changes i would replace The panel.

Answer (score 5):

Well done with all the pics! You'd be amazed how many people *don't* think of that.

**NO!** You cannot simply replace a 15 amp breaker with a 20 amp breaker *unless*... **ALL** the wiring protected by that breaker is 12AWG. If there is *any* 14AWG wire *anywhere* in the circuit, you're creating a fire hazard. 14AWG isn't designed to handle 20 amps

Comment: 4X40A 2-pole (240V) breakers = 8 spaces. There are only 5 spaces free.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I think the OP stated  4 - 40 Amp breakers but that does seem low.

Comment: The OP also stated that is was a "36KW 240V 150A" heater. So 160A at 240V (8 spaces) is plausible while 80A at 240V or 160A at 120V (4 spaces) is not. Frankly, I doubt this is feasible at all - turn on the range while running the dishwasher, perhaps the dryer, and manage to get a main trip on the 200A feed. A 150A water heater is one heck of a load when it's on, and I really doubt that the rest of the house will be consistently happy on the 40 or 50 A left over.

Comment: We also have to remember that resistance heaters are limited to 48a on a 60 amp breaker or multiples as it sounds like the MFG has specified. NEC 424.22

Comment: Also remember OP is proposing a heat pump, and that will take ??? Amps of emergency heat.

Comment: Points taken on the space available in the panel. I misunderstood. The first point does still stand, so I'll remove the 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, the wire is 12/2 Romex on that entire line.

Comment: That's good to hear, @AngelD213. If you're 100% certain that there's 12AWG on the whole run to every outlet & fixture, you should be good to go. Be sure to heed the advice in the other answers here about your water heater situation - they know far more about this than I do!

Comment: Yes, I've checked the whole line as I've been upgrading all of my home outlets and switches. According to the manufacturer, the self-modulating tankless water heater requires 4 x 40 AMP double pole breakers, and the max draw will be 150 amps but it's usually under that. They recommended the house electrical service be no less than 200 amps. The $600 tankless would be less than 10 feet from the electrical panel.

Comment: I guess I should get a new electrical panel to allow those things and hive the microwave/refrigerator with their own dedicated breakers and also upgrade the service to 300/400 amps for future-proofing the addition of a future central heat pump. I'm no expert on this stuff and it is at times confusing, so I thank you for responding in a non-mocking way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the responses you received, you can’t exchange a 15amp breaker for a 20amp without changing the wire size to #12. In regards to changing the entire panel....the size of the wire feeding the new panel will have to be increased to handle the potential load of the new panel. In my area microwaves, refrigerators, and dishwashers all require a dedicated 20amp circuit. I also agree that tankless water heaters are too expensive, the payback/break even time is too long. Standard water heaters are pretty efficient, just check that they aren’t set too high. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another "answer" to be sure to consider flow rate.  My son decided to use a tankless water heater (fairly large one), but didn't consider flow rates needed.  I was showing the house to a builder friend of mine and he spotted the fancy, multi head, high flow rate shower in the MB and then noticed the tankless.  Took a look at the tankless and he said, no way can that support the flow rate needed for the shower.  So after discussions with the plumber decided to add a SECOND tankless WH!

So please consider the flow rate needed and that your tankless can support it.

Comment: Even without a high flow shower for maximum efficiency with tankless units the temp is supposed to be set to the temp Water being used. This water doesn’t take as long to get to the point of use because the hot tap is almost full open. then there is the need for hot water in the kitchen point of use to bring the temp up for the sink and dishwasher.  In 3 bathroom homes someone was always using water while someone was in the shower so you crank the temp up or add additional point of use tankless heaters because tankless do ok with a constant flow but fluctuate when the demand varies.

Comment: I also think they don't play well with HW re-circ systems. Wouldn't they cycle a lot?   I have an indirect water heater (tank) with re-circ. It's so nice to get HW within 3 seconds at every faucet in the house.

Comment: That can be overcome but then you turn your plumbing into a storage system kind of defeats the tankless idea.

Comment: @EdBeal  Agreed, But I have an in-floor hydronic heating system that is the major load on the 2 boilers. The indirect heat water heater is kinda a byproduct of that system. The system is plumbed so that if there is a call for DHW heating only part of the system comes on...basically a circ pump between the boilers and the indirect water heater.   When there is a call for DHW the boiler (usually just one) runs for quite a while at a lower temp so I get good condensation efficiency and it doesn't short cycle.

Comment: To tell the truth a heat pump boiler makes the most sense for a hydronic system The problem with most heat pumps there efficiency drops off at freezing when you need it most I think ours works into the teens , but then wood or pellet is more economical in the Pacific Northwest.

Comment: @EdBeal When we built our house I was thinking of a Water Furnace Heat Pump for the hydronic. Ground loops buried to absorb heat from the ground. But when the calcs were done and the vast amount of trenching needed for the tubing it got ridiculously expensive.